# Linux gets stuck in shutdown process

Tags: xorg, shutdown, suspend

I decided to take my problem to this site, as I have the following issue with Ubuntu 17.03, 16.04 AND Debian 8 stable...

I own an Asus Notebook that had several distributions installed... I noticed that my notebook is sometimes not shutting down properly (screen gets black, but distribution's shutdown screen doesn't show, hard drive then idles and just sometimes shows a little activity). Because I'm interest in how Linux works, I tried looking for an error myself... No entry in the syslog and pm-log, kernel doesn't panic... Months passed and I'm now thinking that the notebook doesn't shutdown when it was in suspended mode before and I'm assuming (without any evidence) that the Xserver is doing some strange things (desktop environment seems to crash because there's still a part of the screen in the top left corner). But TBH, I'm not able to get useful information out of the logs. 
It happened again last night, so I will provide logs if asked to.

I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Try and switch to console mode and then initiate a shutdown with "shutdown -P 0" See if that is successful.

Comment: it is not... to be specific, I can't even switch to terminal mode anymore... That's why I think something's messing with Xorg